# How to pass array of structs as argument on etherscan (tuple[])?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, etherscan

I'm trying to pass the format of array of structs as argument on smart contract write function on etherscan,

This is solidity example:

Info[] public info;

```
struct Info { 
    address userAddress;
    uint256 amount;   
    bool active; 
}
```

[image]
Javascript example:

```
const data = [{0x0000, 10000000000, false},{0x11111, 20000000000, true}]
```

Can anyone convert this data example to tuple[] and provide it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add the value in Etherscan input like this:

```
[["0x0000", "10000000000", false],["0x11111", "20000000000", true]]
```

Comment: I have a struct

struct PricingOption {
        uint208 price;
        uint40 numberOfEntries;
}

I tried to pass params the same way as you wrote and it didn't work for me: invalid tuple value